# How do I set an unable to kick members with higher role - Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

i need some help with this code from my friend using Discord.js. I can't quite seem to code this, what i wanted is :

When the person / member role is higher than the bot, the bot will send a message that the bot is unable to kick the member with the higher role, but when the person below the bot's role will be kicked

The error is :
The bot is unable to kick all members above or below the bot's role

Any solution to this? Maybe i'm missing something

```js
        const rolepositionerror = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription('You can\'t kick members with equal or higher position!')
        .setColor("FF0000")

            const targetMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
 
            const authorHighestRole = message.member.roles.highest
            const targetHighestRole = targetMember.roles.highest
        if(targetHighestRole = authorHighestRole) return message.channel.send(rolepositionerror)

        if(targetMember) {
                targetMember.kick()
                message.channel.send(userkicked)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js's [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has a property called [`GuildMember#kickable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable)  which will return true if the user can be kicked, what you want to do is add it to your code:

---

```js
const targetMember = message.mentions.members.first()
  || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if(targetMember) {
  if (targetMember.kickable) {
    // If you can kick the member, then...

    targetMember.kick()
    message.channel.send(userkicked)
  } else {
    // If you can't kick the member, then...

    const roleError = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(
        "This member can't be kicked!\n" +
        "Check if they have a higher role than the bot and if the bot has permissions!"
      )
      .setColor("FF0000");
    return message.channel.send(roleError)
  }
}
```

---

For more info, check out these links:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Kicking a member](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-kick-a-user)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html)
- [Discord.js - Docs - `GuildMember` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
- [Discord.js - Docs - `GuildMember#kickable` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable)