# How can I disable kicking members who have a higher role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm currently creating a `kick command` and I ran into a problem:

All members are able to kick other members, even if they have a higher role, e.g. a `"normal"` user can kick a `admin` or `mod`. But I want the bot to return a `message` like

> "You can't kick members with equal or higher roles!"

This is my current code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, User } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../configs/config.json');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "kick",
    },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    title: 'You are unable to kick members',
                    color: config.embedcolor
                }
            })
        }
        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    title: 'PLease mention a user',
                    color: config.embedcolor
                }
            })
        }
        if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE-MESSAGES", "ADMINISTRATOR"))
            return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    title: "I can't kick staff members!",
                    color: config.embedcolor
                }
            })

        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        try {
            await member.kick();
            await message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    title: `${member} has been kicked!`,
                    color: config.embedcolor
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            return message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    title: `User isn't in this server!`,
                    color: config.embedcolor
                }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set an unable to kick members with higher role - Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822973/how-do-i-set-an-unable-to-kick-members-with-higher-role-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```js
if(message.member.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest) > 0){
    //member has higher role then first mentioned member
    if(member.kickable){  //Just in case
        message.mentions.members.first().kick();
    }
}else{
    message.reply("You can't kick your senpai °^°");
}
```

**Edit: In latest discord.js version `highestRole` has been replaced with `roles.highest`**

Comment: No need, Just put this code where you're kicking the member. (Using `.kick()` )

Comment: (node:6160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:150:19)     
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:45:28)       
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Permissions.js:45:85)    
    at Object.run (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\commands\mod\kick.js:25:40)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\events\guild\message.js:26:34

Comment: That's error with your code `.hasPermissions()` takes array input. Just put them like this `.hasPermissions(["ADM...R", "KICK....RS"])` also I noticed you used both `permissions.has()` and `.hasPermissions()` in your code. You know it's a bad practice

Comment: its says TypeError: message.member.hasPermissions is not a function

Comment: Oops sorry it's `.hasPermission()`

Comment: im sry but it gives this error when i try to kick someone higher then the author's role UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:150:19)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:45:28)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\daimk\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Permissions.js:45:85)

Comment: Use .`hasPermission()` instead of `permissions.has()` (I thought `permission.has()` was still in beta)

Comment: i tried to kick a staff and it kicked him and when i try to kick someone higher the bot doesn't reply

Comment: Wait where's the logic ? That wasn't supposed to happen

Comment: idk why that is happening

Comment: @Antrayo Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822973/how-do-i-set-an-unable-to-kick-members-with-higher-role-discord-js)

Comment: doesn't work do you mind getting on discord and pls helping me out its been long i just cant fihure it out

Comment: i can reupload bc u cannot see that code sompletely so i will now

Comment: nvm its not letting me upload rn

Comment: @Akio but ur username is in your bio :D

Comment: @Toasty but not his tag

Comment: Have you tried adding akio? Bc I get an error message that he retrieves no invites. Seems like he‘s good with discord.js and I could need help too

Comment: @Toasty add him where?

Comment: @Antrayo on Discord

Comment: @Toasty i dont have his discord mine is Antra#8271

Comment: @Akio I‘m getting the error message that u don’t accept invites, you have to add me

Comment: @Akio would be nice if you could change that setting so I can add you

Comment: @Akio Thx, I've sent a request